There exist a path of length $\chi(G)- 1$ in a connected graph G
For any undirected connected graph $G$, let $\chi (G) $ be its chromatic number. Then for every vertex $v$ in $G$, there exists a path of length $\chi (G)  - 1$ starting from $v$.
My approach : for any vertex $v$, we consider all the paths starting from $v$. Now consider the path of maximum length from $v$. Let the length be $L$. If $L>\chi(G) $ then we are done. But if $L<\chi(G) $ then somehow I have to contradict either the path length or the chromatic number of $G$. I can't proceed further....

As a comment, you can show that a much stronger statement is true, and the strengthening is well known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem

Claim : If we remove a vertex of degree atmost $\chi$ (G) - 2, then the graph is still $\chi$ (G) chromatic.
proof of claim : Let, v be a vertex of G such that d(v) $\leq\chi$ (G) - 2.
If possible let, after deleting the vertex v from G, the new graph becomes $\chi$ (G) - 1 chromatic.Then the color of v in G is unique in G.
Since d(v) $\leq\chi$ (G) - 2, then there exist a color C in $\chi$ (G) such that that coloured vertex is not adjacent to v. Then we can color v with that color C, which is a contradiction to the chromatic number of G.
Hence our clain is true. Then we delete all the vertex of G with degree $\leq\chi$ (G) - 2 and form a new graph H, where every vertex has degree $\geq\chi$ (G) - 1.
Choose a vertex $v_1 \in H$ since $d(v_1)\geq\chi$ (G) - 1 then there exists $v_2 \in H$ which is adjacent to $v_1$
since $d(v_2)\geq\chi$ (G) - 1 then there exists $v_3 \in H$ which is adjacent to $v_2$ , other than $v_1$
Continuing this process we get a path of length $\chi$ (G) - 1 in H from any vertex of H.
Now since G is connected then from any vertex in G-H, there exists a minimum path to H, using that we get a path of length $\chi$ (G) - 1 in G.

I think there might be some justification needed to your following claim: "then we delete all the vertex of $G$ with degree $\leq \chi(G) - 2$ and form a new graph $H$, where every vertex has degree $\geq \chi(G) -1$. You are claiming that removing all low degree vertices from a graph leaves a graph with large minimum degree, which may not be true.

Consider $n$ cycles (of arbitrary length). Choose one vertex from each cycle and connect it to a new vertex, say $v$. Every vertex other than $v$ has degree $\leq 3$, but removing all vertices of degree $\leq 3$ leaves you with a single vertex, not a graph with large minimum degree.

In your last example $\chi$(G) is 2 or 3 (according to length of cycle) then $\chi$(G) - 2 is 0 or 1. But there are no vertex of that degree.

The counterexample provided is not a counterexample to the claim: "deleting all vertices of degree $\leq \chi(G) - 2$ leaves a graph of degree $\geq \chi(G) - 1$". Rather, it is a counterexample to the claim: "deleting all vertices of degree $\leq k-2$ leaves a graph of degree $\geq k-1$", for an integer $k$. I'm not saying that the first claim is wrong -- it could very well be true! I'm saying that when proving the first claim, at least to the reader, you are invoking the second claim, which is false.

The statement is an easy consequence of the following preposition, which you can find in Diestel:

Prep. (Diestel 5.2.2) Every $k$-chromatic graph has a subgraph of minimum degree at least $k-1$.

Once you find a subgraph of large minimum degree, it is easy to find long path.

As an addendum, such proposition essentially combines two statements: a) Every $k$-chromatic graph has a $k$-(vertex) critical subgraph; b) Every $k$-(vertex) critical graph has minimum degree at least $k-1$. Here statement a) can be proven either by induction or considering a maximal critical subgraph, while statement b) can be proven by contradiction.

@koifish I don't get it fully, can you be more descriptive please.

What precisely do you not get?

According to the Prop 5.2.2 (you mentioned), we will get a subgraph H of G such that $$d(v) \geq \chi (G) - 1 \quad \forall v \in H. $$ But what the next? How do we construct path of length $\chi (G) - 1$ starting from v for each $v \in H$?

I claim that if a graph has minimum degree $k$, then there is a path of length $k$. Construct the path recursively as follows: Step $0$: first pick any vertex $v \in V(G)$ and add it into the path. For $1 \leq i \leq k$, Step $i$ involves choosing a neighbor of the last added vertex not chosen before and adding it into the path. As $\delta(G) \geq k$, at Step $i$, you have $\geq k-i+1 \geq 1$ vertices to choose from, so this procedure will always be valid. At the end, you will end up with a path of length $k$.
